# What C++ library do I need to play an AVI on Windows XP?

Tags: library, c++, video-player

I want this to be able to run on an old 32 bit laptop that is limited in ability. I am using Code::Blocks 17.12 (20 will not load). Command line answer or GUI answer; either is usable. There might be an API that I am not aware of, or some code that I have not tried, or you might have made something like this years ago and can show me that code.

If you understand the question, then you might have worked through this years ago. I tried OpenCV; I tried OpenGL; I tried ActiveX; The vast amount of bloat code that accompanies those is beyond what will fit on my old laptop.

I am looking for something simple that runs in C++. It needs to play a small (~ 10 second) AVI in a window that is in my C++ GUI program. No need for any user controls at all. That is it. Windows Media Player is outside of my program therefore not usable.

I do not want some third party program that my code runs outside of my program. I want a C++ library.

- Windows 7 sp0 (for now, later it should work on XP)
- Code::Blocks 17.12
- MinGW GCC (whatever comes with CB-17.12)
- No Visual (Basic, C++, Studio, etc.)

Edit:

I found the answer. It was simple but hidden. I am done with this question here. Thank you all that tried to answer the question. TMSZ was closest so I selected his answer as the most correct.

Comment: "old 32 bit laptop" doesn't narrow which version of Windows XP OS / what libraries the device is running. You also don't mention which compiler/tool chain you are using. Unclear if you found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/mci Alternatively search for "C/C++ Microsoft Windows Programming" books (pdf) published when XP was released may provide what you seek.

Comment: You need a small C++ library to play AVI, right? Maybe something like https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlcpp?

Comment: @Morrison Chang Thank you for the link to mci. I have now studied mci and found that it requires Microsoft Visual Studio or Visual something all of which I have found does not work well or fit on my laptop with what else is there. MCI is not an option. Books on the subject sounds reasonable. Thank you for your help. I am using Windows XP (32 bit) Service Pack 1 (sp2 clashes with other software that I use).

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul, Thank you for the suggestion. I think that you are correct that I need a small C++ library to play AVI. videolan and libvlcpp might be the best idea if they do not require Visual Studio stuff, and if I can get them to work with Code::Blocks 17.12. 
I have been aggressively studying this, but it is so complicated that sometimes I have had to stop and do something else for a while before studying more about it.

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul, I downloaded lots of these files, and lots of examples, but I have  not yet attempted anything in Code::Blocks 17.12 that works. 


I cannot use Code::Blocks 20 since it refuses to install unless I have some Windows 10 file(s) loaded first. According to wikipedia, avi files have been around for more than 20 years, so some simple code for this should be available. I am still trying to find a way to use videolan and libvlcpp. Thank you. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would check that any video file is playable on the default media player app on your old laptop. AVI is a video container format but the codecs/bitrate within the file may be not playable (or at least very choppy) on your device, i.e. a 1080p video file probably exceed the capabilities of a 20 yr old laptop.

Comment: @Morrison Chang, Thank you. I am now checking. OK, "drop.avi" from https://www.engr.colostate.edu/me/facil/dynamics/avis.htm works for me. I downloaded it and tried it. It opens up in VLC player, and plays. I guess that means that something on my laptop is decrypting or decoding it: right? If I could play at least that inside of a GUI window in my program (as I have described), that would be OK. Thank you.

Comment: The codec of that "drop.avi" file is "Indeo Video v4 (IV41)" which was a Intel originated proprietary codec. I don't know if VLC is running its own version but more likely than not VLC is using a Windows library to decode, so I'm more likely to think your plan should work. From what read, the format was discontinued due to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Morrison Chang, Thank you for the Indeo Video v4 (IV41). More to study in the right direction. If I update my code attempt (which I pasted here) should I leave this which I showed (here), or how do I add that in a proper manner? Thank you.

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul, Thank you for your extensive editing of my question. I shall study this and attempt to learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a simple file ("AVI" tells nothing) you might use "Animate" from CommCtrl (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725265/play-avi-using-animation-control).
Otherwise I would go with mplayer in slave mode (https://github.com/tomek-o/VideoPlayer/blob/master/VideoPlayer/MplayerOpenSource.cpp) or libmpv (but I'm not sure about XP compatibility here).

Comment: Thank you. I will now study CommCtrl via your link. I remember that it was powerful in Visual Basic 6. But, I would be looking to use it in C++11 with a GCC compiler via Code::Blocks. I might test mmplayer "in slave mode", which I did not know existed, before I get back to you also. Thank you.

Comment: I have been reading https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/editing-help I will try to use that (next question.).